# RegionPlot and ColorFunction strangely inaccurate in Mathematica 12.3

Tags: color, plotting

Here is a simple example of a `RegionPlot` of a disk with a user-defined `ColorFunction` that is supposed to be rendered with high quality according to my expectation. However, both the disk boundary is not rendered very precisely (polygon shape is recognizable despite `PlotPoints -> 100` and `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"`) and the color function is very imprecisely reflected as well. Is this a problem with Mathematica 12.3 or is the problem in my formulation?

```
pts = Thread[RandomPoint[Disk[], 10] -> RandomColor[10]];
RegionPlot[
  Disk[],
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Nearest[pts, {x, y}]],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
  PlotPoints -> 100
]
```

[image: Screenshot 1]

**Update 1:** Using ciao's suggestion to use `MaxRecursion`, I get the following result for `MaxRecursion -> 9`. The problem with the boundary remains however. Note that the result below uses another random value for `pts`.

[image: Screenshot 2]

**Update 2:** I noted that the boundary is drawn more accurately when using `RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, ...]`. One way to fix the problem with `Disk[]` is using `RegionPlot[RegionConvert[Disk[], "Implicit"], ...]`. This concludes the solution. However, in my opinion the behavior of `RegionPlot[Disk[], ...]` should be considered a bug.

Comment: Up the `MaxRecursion` for the color issue.

Comment: @ciao: Thanks, `MaxRecursion -> 9` looks somewhat decent although rather computationally expensive. Do you know why `PlotPoint -> 100` does not have the desired effect on the quality of the boundary?

Comment: Possibly an “improvement” of the underlying functionality means that the additional functions are necessary to get performance that is more accurate that it would have been before.